# Elegant way to stop release compilation with error

Tags: c#

As you're developing you often use things like

```
throw new NotImplementedException("Finish this off later")
```

or

```
// TODO - Finish this off later
```

as a placeholder to remind you to finish something off - but these can be missed and mistakenly end up in the release.

You could use something like

```
#if RELEASE
   Finish this off later
#endif
```

so it won't compile in Release build - but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Create a technical debt task (JIRA, TFS, CQ, whatever)?

Comment: BTW, I would argue that such check should be a part of build process, maybe check in instead? Most of version control systems have hooks which can handle such cases.

Comment: @Snowbear So you don't let them check in until everything is finished - or you just don't build it with a TODO?

Comment: @weston, yep, what's a point in checking in if you will not build it?

Comment: @Snowbear backup, history, and all the other benefits of source control. I might be working on something for weeks or longer before building it as a release.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I saw an elegant implementation [here](http://ondevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/04/alternative-to-notimplementedexception.html)

```
#if DEBUG

namespace FakeItEasy
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

    /// <summary>
    /// An exception that can be thrown before a member has been
    /// implemented, will cause the build to fail when not built in 
    /// debug mode.
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design",   
        "CA1032:ImplementStandardExceptionConstructors", 
        Justification = "Never used in production.")]
    public class MustBeImplementedException
        : Exception
    {
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: @crazy2be - you make your unfinished methods throw the `MustBeImplementedException`. The compiler directive `#if DEBUG` makes sure that the `MustBeImplementedException` class is only compiling in debug, so for the release build any forgotten throw will result in the build breaking because the class is not available.

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend to use `#warning`:

```
#warning Finish this off later
```

And in the `Release` configuration set [`Treat Warnings as Errors`](http://visualstudiotips.wordpress.com/2006/04/16/tip-treat-warnings-as-errors/) to `True`.

In this case in Debug you will see it only as warnings but in release it will throw exceptions.

Comment: Problem is there are some warnings that we want to ignore (e.g. calling API methods now marked [obsolete] in new version but where we want single source for old/new version.

Comment: You can configure what types of warnings should be ignored. Here is related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267168/treat-all-warnings-as-errors-except-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `#error` and `#warning` directives to throw your own build errors and warnings:

```
#if RELEASE
#error Not finished!
#endif
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8tk0xsk(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I like it so + but PHeibergs answer has the benefit of being a one liner in use so I gave him the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could encapsulate this in it's own method, that way it only has to be changed in one place for a release build.

```
void NotImplemented()
{
    #if RELEASE
        Finish this off later
    #endif
}
```